# Gradiente no Sass

Tags: sass

Estou montando meu projeto, e há uma barra que eu gostaria de colocar um gradiente com três cores, um vermelho claro , um vermelho escuro , e um vermelho claro denovo , como faria esse gradiente em sass ?

è essa Barra eu só consegui deixar um gradiente de duas cores
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem um exemplo? Uma imagem? Etc?

Comment: @Renan acabei de editar a pergunta

Comment: Isso pode ser feito em css normalmente. O que você quer cobrir com Sass? Ser *crossbrowser*? Não está clara a dúvida.

Comment: Veja se é isso que você quer http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: valeu Leandro era isso mesmo que eu queria